# SQL Query to Track Production Operations Outcome Progression with Conditional NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a SQL Server database where I need to track the progression of outcomes for production operations. Each operation (OP) is attempted until it succeeds (outcome=1). If an operation fails (outcome=0), it's retried for a given amount of times, if it passes, after which we proceed to the next operation.

The operations are stored in a table named Operations like the following:

| id | OP | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | 0 |
| 7 | 4 | 0 |
| 8 | 4 | 1 |
| 9 | 5 | 0 |
| 10 | 5 | 1 |

I want to create a view that displays the outcome of each operation across rows in a specific format. If an operation fails, the subsequent operations in that row should display as NULL until the operation succeeds. Here's an example of the desired output format for 5 operations:

| OP 1 Outcome | OP 2 Outcome | OP 3 Outcome | OP 4 Outcome | OP 5 Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I've attempted to structure a query using window functions and conditional aggregation to pivot the data, but I'm struggling with correctly propagating the outcomes and handling the NULLs for subsequent operations after a failure.

The best result I get so far is showed in [this fiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=c66c9cd5-5ce1-45fd-8a80-ecd7a612840b), but I can't figure it out ho to coalesce the NULL value for the already succeeded operation.

Comment: Is, there an identity column

Comment: In your fiddle this would fill in the null values with ones: `case when max(op) > 1 then 1 end as op1outcome, ...` Of course you still need to collapse sequences of ones into a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every zero is the end of a logical group (with an implied zero at the end.) Count off the zeroes in reverse order. The aggregates are a little more complicated that I originally thought but it works:

```
with dataX as (
    select *,
        -count(case when outcome = 0 then 1 end) over (order by id desc) as grp
    from ops
)
select
    grp,
    case when max(op) > 1 then 1 else max(case when op = 1 then outcome end) end as op1outcome,
    case when max(op) > 2 then 1 else max(case when op = 2 then outcome end) end as op2outcome,
    case when max(op) > 3 then 1 else max(case when op = 3 then outcome end) end as op3outcome,
    case when max(op) > 4 then 1 else max(case when op = 4 then outcome end) end as op4outcome,
    case when max(op) > 5 then 1 else max(case when op = 5 then outcome end) end as op5outcome
from dataX
group by grp;
```

OP realized a variation of my first attempt would successfully produce the same result via an analytic `max()`. I had realized that that query wouldn't run without wrapping some of the bare columns with aggregates (or adding to the `group by` as OP did. The version here avoids that in favor of aggregates and `case` expressions. This second approach might have an advantage if operations could be skipped over but I think another intention was to avoid the use of `select distinct` and produce a simpler query plan.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```sql
SELECT  CASE WHEN max(OP) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN OP = 1 THEN Outcome END) END AS OP1
,   CASE WHEN max(OP) > 2 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN OP = 2 THEN Outcome END) END AS OP2
,   CASE WHEN max(OP) > 3 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN OP = 3 THEN Outcome END) END AS OP3
,   CASE WHEN max(OP) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN OP = 4 THEN Outcome END) END AS OP4
,   CASE WHEN max(OP) > 5 THEN 1 ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN OP = 5 THEN Outcome END) END AS OP5
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   sum(flag) OVER(ORDER BY OP, Outcome rows BETWEEN unbounded preceding AND CURRENT row) AS counter
    
    FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        ,   CASE WHEN (lag(outcome) OVER(ORDER BY op,outcome) = outcome AND outcome = 1) OR (lag(outcome) OVER(ORDER BY op,outcome) <> outcome AND outcome = 0)
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END AS flag
        FROM    (
            VALUES  (1, 0)
            ,   (1, 0)
            ,   (1, 1)
            ,   (2, 1)
            ,   (3, 1)
            ,   (4, 0)
            ,   (4, 0)
            ,   (4, 1)
            ,   (5, 0)
            ,   (5, 1)
        ) t (OP,Outcome)
        ) x
    ) x
GROUP BY x.counter
```

1. What you need is to create "level" which seems to be increased every time a new failure arrives or for a new success, i call this field `flag`.
2. Then you create a counter which calculates sum of this flag, this creates the actual level.
3. Finally, you do the conditional aggregation which generates the column. To handle 1 after the Operation is finished i use `CASE WHEN max(OP) > 1 THEN 1` construct.

Output:

| OP1 | OP2 | OP3 | OP4 | OP5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

See example.

```
with t as (
select *
  ,sum(case when po=0 then 1 else 0 end)over(order by rn)grn
from (
   select *,lag(outcome,1,0)over(order by rn)po
   from (select *,row_number()over(order by op,outcome)rn from ops)ops
  )x
)
,t2 as(
 select *
   ,max(case when op=1 then outcome end)over(order by rn)moutcome1
   ,max(case when op=2 then outcome end)over(order by rn)moutcome2
   ,max(case when op=3 then outcome end)over(order by rn)moutcome3
   ,max(case when op=4 then outcome end)over(order by rn)moutcome4
   ,max(case when op=5 then outcome end)over(order by rn)moutcome5
  from t
)
select grn
  ,case when sum(moutcome1)>0 then 1 when sum(moutcome1)=0 then 0 end op1
  ,case when sum(moutcome2)>0 then 1 when sum(moutcome2)=0 then 0 end op2
  ,case when sum(moutcome3)>0 then 1 when sum(moutcome3)=0 then 0 end op3
  ,case when sum(moutcome4)>0 then 1 when sum(moutcome4)=0 then 0 end op4
  ,case when sum(moutcome5)>0 then 1 when sum(moutcome5)=0 then 0 end op5
from t2
group by grn
```

Output

| grn | op1 | op2 | op3 | op4 | op5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | null | null | null | null |
| 2 | 0 | null | null | null | null |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | null |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | null |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: No. Your answer is very different. And I  couldn't test it - ``Column 'dataX.OP' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`` See fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/sN_RXv8U) You may have missed some necessary step.